# order results from table A by total number of related rows form table B

Tags: sql, sqlite

i have two tables, "topics" (table A) and "topic votes" (table B). each "topic" has multiple "topic votes". i need to select rows from "topics" and order them by the total number of related "topic votes".

how is it possible in sqlite? do i need to create a view for this, or is it possible to solve with JOIN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the votes you can just put a correlated query in the `order by`:

```
select t.*
from topics t
order by (select count(*) from topic_votes tv where t.topic = v.topic) desc;
```

Normally, you would want the number of votes in the result set as well.  A simple method is to move the subquery to the `select` clause:

```
select t.*,
       (select count(*) from topic_votes tv where t.topic = v.topic
       ) as votes
from topics t
order by votes desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a PK id in `topics` table and FK topic_id in `topic votes` table:

```
select
    t.*
from topics t
left join topic_votes v on t.id = v.topic_id
group by t.id
order by count(v.topic_id) desc;
```